# Instantiating a progress bar that runs asynchronously and modifying it with thread safe calls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application I have a queue download list which consists of progress bars and the file names. When the user clicks a button the file name and progress bar is instantiated and added to the queue. Files download one at a time and asynchronously. What I want to do is keep all the progress bars of the files that are waiting to be downloaded yellow in color and then turn green when it is being downloaded and then turn blue when they are completed. It currently works if I have `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` in the constructor of the custom progress bar. I want to see if there is a way to make thread safe changes to the progress bars.

I have each queue item set up as an object. The queue item objects are created from the main form code (Form1.cs) when a button is pressed and the progress bars are created in the queue item constructor, which is probably where my problem begins. The downloads are started through a function in the queue item object.

**Queue Item Snippet**

```
 public class QueueItem
 {
    public bool inProgress;
    public QueueBar bar;

    public QueueItem(args)
    {
         bar = new QueueBar();
         inProgress = false;
         // handle arguments
    }

    public void Download()
    {
        // process info
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(url, @savePath);
    }

    private long lastByte = 0;
    private long newByte = 0;
    private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        percentValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
        bar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        newByte = e.BytesReceived;
    }

    private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // change bar color
        bar.Value = 100;
    }
 }
```

**Queue Bar Snippet**

```
public class QueueBar : ProgressBar
{
    // variables

    public QueueBar()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);     
        // initialize variables
    }

    // function to change text properties
    // function to change color

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // painting
    }
}
```

**Main Function Snippet**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<QueueItem> qItems;
    private BackgroundWorker queue;

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // basic gist of it
        qItems.Add(new QueueItem(args));
        Label tmpLabel = new Label();
        tmpLabel.Text = filename;
        tmpLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottm;
        splitContainerQueue.Panel2.Controls.Add(tmpLabel);
        splitContainerQueue.Panel2.Controls.Add(qItems[qItems.Count - 1].bar);

        if (!queue.IsBusy) { queue.RunWorkerAsync(); }
    }

    private void queue_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (qItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!qItems[0].inProgress && qItems[0].percentValue == 0)
            {
                qItems[0].inProgress = true;
                qItems[0].Download();
            }
            // else if statements
        }
 }
```

I also just tried creating a background worker to create the Queue Items and add the controls asynchronously but that doesn't work since the split container was created on a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a UI control (created on your UI thread) from another thread safely - you need to use [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) / [`BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) for such calls. When calling `BeginInvoke()` you'll pass a delegate; something like this (just some sample code, yours will look slightly different):

```
private void SomeEventHandler ( object oSender, EventArgs oE )
{
    if ( InvokeRequired )
    {
        MethodInvoker oDelegate = (MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            SomeEventHandler ( oSender, oE );
        };

        BeginInvoke ( oDelegate );
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // already on the correct thread; access UI controls here
    }
}
```

You also cannot create your progress bars away from the UI thread - you need to create all your controls as part of your UI and then if you need to access these progress bars from your queue items, you'll have to pass in a reference to the progress bar. When you try to access the progress bar, you'll do

```
if ( bar.InvokeRequired ) { ... }
```

to determine if you're trying to call it from the right thread.

The reason for this mess is because controls handle many of their property updates through messages and those messages must be delivered synchronously, in the correct order. The only way to ensure this (without some very complex coding) is to create all controls on the same thread where the thread runs a message pump.

Comment: I definitely avoid using self-recursive invoke handlers like this. I have seen many scenarios where InvokeRequired always returns true, and you end up in a tail-less recursion (or a stack overflow if you're just using Invoke).
A simple modification to split the InvokeRequired call to another method which doesn't do the InvokeRequired check again, will sort this out.

Comment: @Adam in what situation have you seen that? I've used this kind of setup for a long time and never ran into problems with it. I'm curious what triggers the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Hi xxbbcc - I never nailed it down, but we've had it happen in both C# and WinForms - thankfully our logging pointed out why the CPU was pegging straight away. The design was such an obvious 'risk' being that InvokeRequired is black-box, we have no guarantees about how it's going to behave under failure scenario - it was a no-brainer to make the quick fix and move on, a couple of lines of code makes for massive peace of mind. Just one of the many defensive programming techniques we've picked up over the years.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation xxbbcc, and thanks for the info Adam.